# What's the difference when casting the float and double to int in java?

Tags: java

I used these statements to test

```
float f=4.35f;
int i=(int)(f*100);
System.out.println(i);
double d=4.35;
i=(int)(d*100);
System.out.println(i);
```

the result is

```
 435
 434
```

I used to think the only difference between float and double is just the precision. They should be the same in an calculation. But I converted 4.35 to binary and then converted it back to decimal and found it is in fact 4.3499999...
So if I multiply it by 100 and then cast, I think the answer should be 434 with both float and double. Why the first one is 435?

Comment: Why don't you also look at the value of `f*100` and `d*100`?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @nachokk +1 for this link. You legitimately need to read this.

Comment: @Kon: I disagree.  It makes horrible reading; it gets posted over and over again on SO, but I doubt most people have actually ever read it.

Comment: Simplified version of nachokk link: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are absolutely right

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Most of the regulars in the Java tag on SO that answer questions have likely read it.

Comment: @Kon: I haven't (other than the first few pages), and I don't intend to.  Its content is actually not relevant (or at least, completely overkill) to most questions about floating-point; this one included.

Comment: Print out both values to their full precision, after multiplying by 100.

Comment: There is no difference in the cast. The difference is in the value being cast.

Answer (score 6):

Floating-point in Java uses a binary representation. Many numbers that have a short exact representation in decimal, such as `4.35`, do not have an exact representation in binary at any precision (be it `float`, `double` or another one).

When you write `4.35` in a Java program, it is interpreted as meaning the `double` nearest 435/100. When you write `4.35f`, it is interpreted as meaning the `float` nearest 435/100.

It so happens that both `4.35` and `4.35f` are slightly below 435/100:
in Java, `4.35` represents 4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 exactly and `4.35f` represents 4.349999904632568359375.
In a first approximation, it is just chance that in both types the nearest representable value is below the target 435/100 (although when looking deeper into it, there is nothing random about it).

The number `435` on the other hand is representable exactly as both a `float` and a `double`.

When multiplying `4.35f` or `4.35` by 100 (which is exactly representable as `float` and as `double` too), one of two possibilities happens:

- the mathematical result of the multiplication is closer to 435 than to any other floating-point number. Then `435` is chosen as the result of the operation. You have to remember that Java does not know that it is multiplying a number intended to be 4.35. As far as it knows, you chose a number lower than 4.35 on purpose. Perhaps you really intended the operand to be 4.349999904632568359375. It is the consequence of a second approximation during the multiplication that the end result is 435. Anyway, converting the floating-point number `435` to `int` produces the int `435`. This is what happens in the case of `float`.
- the mathematical result of the multiplication is closest to a floating-point number below 435. In this case, that floating-point number is chosen as the result of the floating-point multiplication. Converting this result to `int` produces `434`, because the conversion from floating-point to integer works by *truncation*. This is what happens in the case of `double`. Multiplying `4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375` by 100 produces a mathematical result that is close to the `double` immediately below `435.0` (this `double` is 434.99999999999994315658113919198513031005859375), and thus this `double` is used as the result of the floating-point multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pascal Cuoq's excellent answer:

The [Multiplication of Floating Point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Multiplication_and_division) basically consists of

- Multiplying the mantissas
- Adding the exponents
- Normalizing the result

In-between, the result of multiplying the mantissas is *rounded* when it can not be represented exactly with the available 23bits (float) or 52 bits (double).

The behavior is described in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4):

> The Java programming language requires that floating-point arithmetic behave as if every floating-point operator rounded its floating-point result to the result precision. Inexact results must be rounded to the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result; if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero is chosen. This is the IEEE 754 standard's default rounding mode known as *round to nearest*.

And as Pascal Cuoq already said: The value `4.35f` can not be presented exactly. When this value is multiplied with `100.0f`, the *nearest representable value* for the result in the above mentioned sense is `435.0`. In contrast to that, for the multiplication of `4.35d` and `100.0d`, the *nearest representable value* for the result is `434.99999999999994...`. And in both cases, the values are truncated to `int` by simply omitting the fractional part, yielding the values of `435` for the `float` case, and `434` for the `double` case, respectively.